# Duplicated rows: select rows based on criteria and store duplicated values

Tags: r, duplicates

I am working on a raw dataset that looks something like this:

```
df <- data.frame("ID" = c("Alpha", "Alpha", "Alpha", "Alpha", 
                          "Beta","Beta", "Beta","Beta" ),
                 "treatment"= LETTERS[seq(from = 1, to = 8)],
                 "Year" = c(1970, 1970, 1980, 1990, 1970, 1980, 
                            1980,1990),
                 "Val" = c(0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1),
                 "Val2" = c(0,2.34,1.3,0,0,2.34,3.2,1.3))
```

The data is a bit dirty as I have multiple observations for each ID and Year identifier - e.g. I have 2 different rows for Alpha in 1970. The same holds for Beta in 1980.

The issue is that the variable of interest `Val` `Val2` have different scores in the duplicated rows (in terms of id/year).

I would like to find a concise way to produce the following final dataframe:

```
final <- data.frame("ID" = c("Alpha", "Alpha", "Alpha", 
                             "Beta", "Beta","Beta" ),
                    "treatment"= c("B","C","D","E","G","H"),
                    "Year" = c(1970, 1980, 1990, 1970, 
                               1980,1990),
                    "Val" = c(0,0,1,0,0,1),
                    "Val2" = c(2.34,1.3,0,0,3.2,1.3),
                    "del_treat" = c("A",NA,NA,NA,"F",NA),
                    "del_Val"=c(0,NA,NA,NA,1,NA),
                    "del_Val2"=c(0,NA,NA,NA,2.34,NA))
```

The logic is the following:

1) I want to have only one obs for every ID/year

2) I want only to retain the observation with a higher value in the `Val2` category.

3) I would like to store the deleted rows values into separate columns to keep track of what I am deleting `del_treat`, `del_Val` and `del_Val2`.

To illustrate. In df there is a duplicated observation for Alpha/1970. I want to reduce this to a single row. Val2 takes the value of 0 and 2.34, and in the final data frame, only 2.34 is retained. However, the values of treatment A are reported in newly created columns `del_treat`, `del_Val` and `del_Val2`.

I am able to select rows based on the ``` Val2``setDT(df)[order(-Val2)][,.SD[1,], by = .(ID, Year)] ```
 value, but I would like to find a concise way to also 'store' the results deleted into the new columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using data.table, a dcast based on `rowid(ID, Year)` after ordering by `Val2` descending gets you there with the exception of column names. The "_1" columns are the "keep" columns, and the "_2" columns are the "del" columns.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

setorder(df, ID, Year, -Val2)

out <- 
  dcast(df, ID + Year ~ rowid(ID, Year), value.var = c('treatment', 'Val', 'Val2'))
out
#       ID Year treatment_1 treatment_2 Val_1 Val_2 Val2_1 Val2_2
# 1: Alpha 1970           B           A     0     0   2.34   0.00
# 2: Alpha 1980           C        <NA>     0    NA   1.30     NA
# 3: Alpha 1990           D        <NA>     1    NA   0.00     NA
# 4:  Beta 1970           E        <NA>     0    NA   0.00     NA
# 5:  Beta 1980           G           F     0     1   3.20   2.34
# 6:  Beta 1990           H        <NA>     1    NA   1.30     NA
```

We can change the names to match yours, only difference is the del columns have a number at the end. Would be useful if there is possiblity of > 2 rows per group.

```
setnames(out, function(x) gsub('(.*)_1', '\\1', x))
setnames(out, function(x) gsub('(.*_\\d+)', 'del_\\1', x))
out
#       ID Year treatment del_treatment_2 Val del_Val_2 Val2 del_Val2_2
# 1: Alpha 1970         B               A   0         0 2.34       0.00
# 2: Alpha 1980         C            <NA>   0        NA 1.30         NA
# 3: Alpha 1990         D            <NA>   1        NA 0.00         NA
# 4:  Beta 1970         E            <NA>   0        NA 0.00         NA
# 5:  Beta 1980         G               F   0         1 3.20       2.34
# 6:  Beta 1990         H            <NA>   1        NA 1.30         NA
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is very efficient!

Answer (score 2):

Here is one option with `dplyr`.  After grouping by 'ID', 'Year', create a logical column ('ind') that checks the `max` of 'Val2', using that create two columns corresponding to 'Val' with 'del' as prefix for those values that are eliminated, as well as the 'treatment' not present, `filter` the rows based on 'ind' and `ungroup`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(ID, Year) %>% 
   mutate(ind = Val2 == max(Val2) & !is.na(Val2)) %>% 
   mutate_at(vars(matches('Val')), 
        list(del = ~ if(any(!ind)) .[!ind] else NA_real_)) %>% 
   mutate(del_treat = if(any(!ind)) treatment[!ind] else NA_character_) %>% 
   filter(ind) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   select(-ind)
```